# Multiple cursors in Sublime Text under Ubuntu

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, sublime-text-2, ubuntu-13.04

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu 13.04 and I'm missing a function in Sublime Text,

On Windows I used the middle mouse button to set multiple cursors (a bit like holding <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and adding cursors but instead of click for each cursor jsut hold the middle mousebtn) but now on Ubuntu I can't find anything like that.

How can I get this functionality back?

is there any super user out there?
for **any** hint thanks in advance

Answer (score 10, accepted):

<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Right Mouse Button</kbd> is the combination for column selection in Linux.

Comment: After that how can you go to the end of the lines for all cursors?

Comment: @aless80 then you work just like with one cursor, all combinations are the same. Go to the end of the line - press End.

Comment: @bruha Sorry, now I see that that was possible. When I wrote my previous command I could not make it work

Comment: There's also the keyboard shortcut. On my stinking Ubuntu 18.04 it was broken for some reason though, so I fixed it. Full explanation here: https://superuser.com/questions/641292/multiple-cursors-in-sublime-text-under-ubuntu/1568729#1568729.

Answer (score 9):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
Will Add a new cursor on the line *above* the current one

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd> 
Will Add a new cursor on the line *under* the current one

Comment: Does not work on Ubuntu 16 for me.

Comment: This works on one of my Ubuntu 18.04 computers, but not the other. I'd really like to know what's going on.

Comment: Solved it! That's been bothering me for MONTHS! What a pain! https://superuser.com/a/1568729/425838

Answer (score 5):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Mouse1Click</kbd> will set another cursor at the location of the click.
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>D</kbd> will highlight the current word, move the cursor to its end, and add another highlight and cursor at the next occurence of that word. Repeated presses will select additional occurences.

Comment: The OP already knows that they can hold `Ctrl` to achieve that, but they want it with the middle mouse button.

Answer (score 3):

## Using/enabling "multi-cursor", "select lines", or "column selection" mode in Sublime Text 3

1. As [@bruha says](https://superuser.com/a/764012/425838), <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Right-mouse-click</kbd> and drag up or down works.
2. As [@russianPopsv says](https://superuser.com/a/1342203/425838), these *should* work on Ubuntu too:

   1. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd>
   2. <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Down</kbd>

In my case, however, on two Ubuntu 18.04 machines <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Up</kbd> worked just fine, but on a third one it wouldn't work at all! I have no idea why. **How do I fix it?**

If it doesn't work for you, then do this:

In Sublime Text 3, go to Preferences --> Key Bindings. Search the left screen for `select_lines`. There are two matches, here:

[image]

They contain these JSON configuration lines:

```
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
{ "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
```

So, copy those into your personal settings screen on the right, so it looks like this. If you have other settings there already, be sure to keep those too.

```
[
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+up"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": false} },
    { "keys": ["alt+shift+down"], "command": "select_lines", "args": {"forward": true} },
]
```

Now save (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>) and exit these keyboard settings by closing the window. That's it! The keyboard shortcuts will work now. I don't know why we had to do this, as they should have worked by default already, but somehow this fixed it, so whatever, it's good enough for me.

## Where did I originally learn how to use multi-cursor ("column selection") mode in Sublime Text? Answer: Sublime Tutor

I originally learned this "column selection", or "multi-cursor" mode from Sublime Tutor (https://sublimetutor.com/). It is described in `chapter_3_2.md`, as shown here:

[image]

It will help you master Sublime Text in no time! It's super super easy to install:

(See: https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Sublime%20Tutor):

> ### Installation
>
> Via Package Control:
>
> 1. Install Package Control if already not installed: https://packagecontrol.io/installation#st3
> 2. Press Cmd+Shift+P to bring command palette in front
> 3. Type Install Package and press enter.
> 4. Search for Sublime Tutor and press enter to install the plugin.

I highly recommend it.

Comment: thank you for that wholesome answer

Answer (score 2):

Copy the relevant mousemap settings from the Windows file to the Linux file.

Windows file: `*~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/Default/Default (Windows).sublime-mousemap*`

You could copy the settings to the linux file in the same directory, however I recommend adding a file in your user folder: `*~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages/User/Default (Linux).sublime-mousemap*`

Relevant settings:

```
// Mouse 3 column select     
[{
  "button": "button3",
  "press_command": "drag_select",
  "press_args": {"by": "columns"}
},
{
  "button": "button3", "modifiers": ["ctrl"],
  "press_command": "drag_select",
  "press_args": {"by": "columns", "additive": true}
},
{
  "button": "button3", "modifiers": ["alt"],
  "press_command": "drag_select",
  "press_args": {"by": "columns", "subtractive": true}
}]
```

This is not included in the Linux settings by default because in linux, mouse 3 is paste.  You can highlight something and use your mouse to paste (without having to copy).